# How to clean up repetetive elements in a C# method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, refactoring, class-library

I'm currently working on a .NET Core 3.1 application.

I need to refactor a code smell to reduce method complexity - in my method there are lots of repetitive elements.

All properties in my class are of type string.
I need to check if the passed reference holds the same value as the property.
If a referenced value differes, I need to set the flag to true and correct the Property value with the referenced one.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
// ... all Properties are of type String!

public bool MyMethod(Apple myApple)
{
    var flag = false;
    myApple.Id = Id;

    if (Name != myApple.Name)
    {
        Name = myApple.Name;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (Description != myApple.Description)
    {
        Description = myApple.Description;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (ShortDescription != myApple.ShortDescription)
    {
        ShortDescription = myApple.ShortDescription;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (Location != myApple.Location)
    {
        Location = myApple.Location;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (KindId != myApple.KindId)
    {
        KindId = myApple.KindId;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (Expiration != myApple.Expiration)
    {
        Expiration = myApple.Expiration;
        flag = true;
    }
    if (PurchaseDate != myApple.PurchaseDate)
    {
        PurchaseDate = myApple.PurchaseDate;
        flag = true;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Do you know how to reduce complexity in my method and perhaps get rid of the repetetive elements?

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Can't really shorten it; it does what you ask it to.  Does seem like an [X Y problem](https://xyproblem.info), though.

Comment: You have working code that is also compile time safe. So better don't replace it with a reflection version that looks shorter but is not compile time safe anymore and also less efficient. The only thing that i would change are the names(flag,MyMethod)

Comment: unfortunately it is a requirement, we use Sonarqube and it detected a critical code smell in my method :(

Comment: why mixing up the comparing bit with the value overriding? you should first check if there is a change (either using reflection or if the objects are the same <<this & Apple>> you can override equals) and if there is a change you simply override with new values (you could do that via Automapper)

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten it a bit by introducing a local function and using one delegate to select the property to compare and another delegate to assign the property.

It would look something like this:

```
public bool MyMethod(Apple myApple)
{
    bool flag = false;

    void assignIfDifferent<T>(Func<Apple, T> selector, Action assign)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(selector(myApple), selector(this)))
            return;

        assign();
        flag = true;
    }

    assignIfDifferent(apple => apple.Name,             () => { this.Name             = myApple.Name;             });
    assignIfDifferent(apple => apple.Description,      () => { this.Description      = myApple.Description;      });
    assignIfDifferent(apple => apple.ShortDescription, () => { this.ShortDescription = myApple.ShortDescription; });
    assignIfDifferent(apple => apple.Location,         () => { this.Location         = myApple.Location;         });

    // Etc etc.

    return flag;
}
```

I'm not really convinced that's an improvement, but that's for you to decide. It does at least reduce the number of lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

If you used fields instead of auto properties you could use the following pattern

```
private string name;
public string Name => name;
public bool MyMethod(Apple myApple)
{
    var flag = false;
    myApple.Id = Id;
    flag |= Set(ref name, myApple.Name);
    flag |= Set(ref description , myApple.Description);
    ...
}

private bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value) where T : IEquatable<T>{
    if(!field.Equals(value)){
        field = value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method can also be combined with [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0) to help raise events for wpf-code.

Doing the same pattern with properties is less neat since you need to either use delegates for setting the value, or reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with using Reflection's. You can iterate all properties of class and control it.

```
var test = (new Apple()).MyMethod(new Apple() { Name = "Stack", Desc = "Test" });   


public class Apple
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Onur";
    public string Desc { get; set; } = "Test";
    // ... all Properties are of type String
    public bool MyMethod(Apple apple)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(this.GetType().GetProperties());
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            try
            {
                //get value in method param
                object propValue = prop.GetValue(apple, null);
                //get current prop in current class
                PropertyInfo propResult = this.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                var val = propResult.GetValue(this, null);
                if (val != propValue)
                {
                    propResult.SetValue(this, propValue, null);
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP, be careful using reflection, you can get carried away pretty quickly and get lulled into a sense of "reflection can fix a lot of things" that, while it might fix things, may also introduce new issues and can be very expensive performance-wise.

Comment: @Daevin you absolutely right. But I just wanna show how to do it another way. But thanks for your information I didn't talk about.

Comment: it's good that an answer using reflection was posted (especially since one of the comments on the question mentions it but doesn't elaborate much), so kudos on providing that. I just wanted to call out a caution to OP. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use something like a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) for all the properties, i.e. just create a new record with all the new properties you want, then compare it to the old one to see if they are equal, using the auto generated equality method. i.e.

```
public record MyProperties(string Name, string Description);
...
private MyProperties props;
public string Name => props.Name;
...
public bool MyMethod(Apple myApple)
{
    var newProps = new MyProperties(
         myApple.Name, 
         myApple.Descrpition);
    var flag = newProps != props;
    props = newProps;
    return flag;
}
```